# How keep prepared courgette fresh?

Tags: food-safety

I am making a pasta dish at school that has courgette in it. The recipe says grate the courgette and because I don't have much time at school to do it, I want to do it at home.

I do not know how to keep them fresh when they have already been prepared.I heard that if you keep grated courgette in water, it stays fresh. I am leaving the house at 7:50 and my lesson starts at 9.

Answer (score 3):

You could totally just grate courgette (zucchini) the morning of your lesson. It will be fine, you don't even have to put it in water. Just put it in a baggie. It would be fine at room temperature for several hours, it's not even going to notice two. If you want to grate it the day before, just put the baggie in the refrigerator overnight.

Comment: Just to back this up, I have in the past had stir fry on my menus at work. Often the vegetables (including courgette) would be prepped and stored for 3 days in a tub with a lid no water, without any deterioration.